# Image to fill div proportionally without using background-size: cover or object-fit: cover

Tags: html, image, css

I'm trying to fill a div with an image while maintaining its aspect ratio. But i do not want to use a background image with background-size: cover or even use the object-fit: cover property, I want the result of them using the img tag.

As you can see in the code below, without using the object-fit: cover or background-size: cover the image is stretched and this is not the result that i want.

```css
.post-thumbnail {
  width: 352px;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-thumbnail">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKh0q0NzNKTmUA9q-uxaJIRx3pNYgbqzEdGW1cXFdIlZ_SlV-M">
</div>
```

In the code below the image is not stretched, due to object-fit: cover, i want this same result without using this property, since it does not have a good compatibility. Does anyone know how can i do this?

```css
.post-thumbnail {
  width: 352px;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-thumbnail">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKh0q0NzNKTmUA9q-uxaJIRx3pNYgbqzEdGW1cXFdIlZ_SlV-M">
</div>
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3 This blog post might be useful

Comment: This propeties were esentially introduced to solve a problem that was unsolvable without them... So no, it's not possible unless you use some script.

Answer (score 1):

you could use clip() + position:absolute, or use negative margins along vertical-align and text-align:

```css
.post-thumbnail {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 352px;
  height: 240px;
                           line-height:240px;
                           text-align:center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.post-thumbnail.small {
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.post-thumbnail img {
                             min-width: 100%;
                             min-height: 100%;
                             vertical-align:middle;
                             margin:-500px;
}

/* demo purpose to show what is being hidden;*/
.post-thumbnail {
  margin:50px;
  overflow: visible;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 50px rgba(200,200,200,0.5);
  border:solid blue;
}

.post-thumbnail img {
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-thumbnail">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKh0q0NzNKTmUA9q-uxaJIRx3pNYgbqzEdGW1cXFdIlZ_SlV-M">
</div>
<div class="post-thumbnail small">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKh0q0NzNKTmUA9q-uxaJIRx3pNYgbqzEdGW1cXFdIlZ_SlV-M">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the height property and the width property, that way you are stretching you page. If you only set one, the other one scales with it. Depending on what kind of picture you have and how you want it, you need to set the height and width.

Comment: With just one set the image is not centered and with width or height:auto the image will be bigger or smaller than the div and this is not what I want.

Comment: Use text-align: center;